# Visual studio cannot find the header files in Additional Include folders

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include

I have been seeing this occasionally, but this project in particular is causing me to tear my hair out.

I have my `.cpp`.

```
#include <nppi.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <device_functions.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
```

The Headers are in My project directory, in:

```
<Project file>\Thirdparty\CUDA\v8.0\include
```

my Additional includes are:

```
$(ProjectDir)Thirdparty\CUDA\v8.0\include
```

i have also tried:

```
Thirdparty\CUDA\v8.0\include
```

The includes are not found by intellisense, and i cannot open them with a right click. What am i doing wrong? or is this a bug?

Even with a hardcoded path in the Additional includes, the files are not found.

I am in Release mode. If i switch to Debug mode, some of the files are found, but some are not. The Additional includes seem to stay the same when I switch, this seems odd. (I have not added additional includes for Debug).

Thank you for your help, this is driving me mad.

Comment: does the project build successfully?

Comment: No, it complains about being unable to find the Headers.

Comment: are you sure that the header files that you have included are actually in the included folder?

Comment: Positive. I have triple checked.

Comment: and if you copy paste the full path to this include dir directly to additional includes it also doesnt work?

Comment: what if you add the include path to VC++ Directories/Include directories ?

Comment: If i put it in the actual `.cpp`, it will work. But break further on, the `#includes` inside the header are not found. If I add the full path to Additional includes, it does not work.

Comment: I tried adding `$(ProjectDir)Thirdparty\CUDA\v8.0\include` to VC++ Directories/Include directories, the evaluated value is correct, but still the headers are not found.

Comment: ... when i copy the evaluated value into a folder, the header is there.

Comment: is there a way to share the project?

Comment: it is huge. i will try to replicate the issue in a new project... Thank you!

Comment: ok i have a test project with the issue. What is the best way to send it?

Comment: you can try with this  http://expirebox.com/ or similar. send the link when you are done

Comment: http://expirebox.com/download/c07bbe6703524a4de292542d17367bcd.html

Comment: Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: I am not able to replicate the error. The includes are found. What if you close the visual studio and open the project file: ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj directly by double clicking. then build in debug.

Comment: Have you tried in release mode? I added the includes in release, yet the project will only build in Debug.

Comment: the project has no includes in release mode (at least when I open it). if I add the same include as it is in debug it builds in release also.

Comment: Strange. That project absolutely will not build for me. Perhaps my vs install is buggy?

Comment: It should ONLY have includes in release mode. i never used Debug mode until after I sent the file to you.

Comment: well it doesnt built for me also due to other errors and linker error, but the header is found. I am sorry. which version of VS are you using?

Comment: 2015 community. which version works for you?

Comment: 2015 proffesional

Comment: I will try uninstall/reinstall, and if that doesn't help, will upgrade. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new folder named "include" in your project directory.
Right-click on the project and then on Properties.
CUDA C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories. Type into the upper half $(ProjectDir)include. it should evaluate this path correctly. Check that!
In your kernel.cu that includes your main-function, type in #include "include\mycode.cu". That worked for me. Good luck!